# Is there a Google Maps like app that shows directions and other people's progress along the same route?

Tags: driving, maps, routes, mobile-apps, gps-navigation

I'm looking for an app that not only shows a route with directions (like Google Maps) but also tracks friends following the same route, with all of them showing at the same time. Think of it as Find my Friends + Google Maps. Ideally I should be able to see multiple friends at the same time.

The reasoning behind this request is that I'm trying to organize a trip, and thought it would be nice to see where my friends are relative to me so far on the route, somewhat like the map in Mario Kart.

Comment: If you're all on WhatsApp, you can all share your location to a group you're all in

Comment: @AakashM I've found that better than Google.  Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @AakashM, unfortunately, WhatsApp is strictly location sharing, but has no features of a GPS map like Google Maps.

Comment: "has no features of a GPS map" - I'm not sure what you mean. A phone's location is shared as precisely as that phone's location settings allow, and the viewer is shown the shared locations on a google map (map / satellite as desired)

Comment: @AakashM My apologies for not being clear. Severely sorry about that. I meant it has location sharing and does show the shared locations on a map, but does not have the feature of choosing a destination and getting directions. For example, if I have 5 different friends in different cities and we want to meet up at destination B, I'd like to get directions to B while also seeing my friend's locations.

Comment: Citymapper has this feature, but only within the areas it supports

Comment: Although this question is already answered, I will point out that it probably ought to have been asked on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Where I would have never seen it and therefore would not have given an answer.

Comment: "friends following the same route" / "I have 5 different friends in different cities and we want to meet up at destination B" - that would be 5 _different routes_, same destination - a different scenario than that stated in the question.

Comment: @MrWhite, a different scenario, but the criteria still stands for each scenario. In both scenarios, I am still asking for a GPS directions feature that shows the locations of my friends at the same time, whether or not they are on the same route.

Comment: The technology certainly exists. For example in the UK the Automobile Association has a breakdown reporting app which automatically transmits your location anywhere in the UK to them from a standard Android phone (and presumably also from Apple). Of course after a breakdown you are unlikely to be moving, but the location request is "on demand" and not at some pre-specified time so that doesn't seem like a limitation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but I would have seen it :-)  I honestly meant no offence, as I hope that I pointed out, just wanted people to be aware of s/w recs :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica No offence was taken. It is a balance between where the mostly likely answer can be found. Here I think you will better results from peaple that **use** this functionality (practical experience), than in software where they may know more about what is on offer.

Comment: Lols! And os s/w recs we strongly prefer that people used the s/w that they are recommending - otherwise, they probably just Googled for it. There are a lot of tough calls out there (e.g code questions on Internet of Things which technically belong on Stack Overflow, where people may not have the IoT experience, etc, etc). Let's just keep answering and helping.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One can use the phone application [Waze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waze) to see one's connections on the same map: https://youtu.be/hGDrzDw2a7s

Note: https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=243565

> It's not really live, it's just an animation that moves the pin at the theoretical speed it should move based on distance + ETA, it's quickly out of sync too unless you refresh the page once in a while. Through the friend sharing you get an updated real location every 2 minutes.

I haven't used the feature for a few years so I don't know its current status.

For a list of applications for tracking friends on a map (but don't show directions), see [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21226/903).

---

https://www.slashgear.com/facebook-buying-waze-in-1bn-social-map-deal-tip-insiders-09281249/:

[image]

https://youtu.be/hGDrzDw2a7s:

[image]

Comment: Man I haven't seen an iPhone like that in ages

Answer (score 16):

Yes, for Google Maps you can share your position (**[Location sharing](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)**) with others (and they with you). I assume a Google Account is needed for both parties. This can be turned on and off when needed. You also get general email reminders that you are still sharing your location information.

In the Google Maps application you can see the persons position, based on their gps signal and are somehow connected to the internet.

I found this to be useful where a visitor regularly wanders around the city during the day, to eventually meet in the late afternoon.

Depending in the gps signal, you can the see if the person is on their way back and get a general idea when they will arrive.

---

> Can one view more than one tracked car at once on Google maps?

You are not locating a car, but a person (or more precisely a Google Account that is logged in to a device) that must be in each car. No mention of a maximum amount of 'friends and family' in their text. So assume that more than one is allowed. In the maps application it is shown as a icon with the name on the map.

When moving on a Bus, then the position will 'hop' every few minutes from one position to another. One should look for any refresh setting that may be possible.

---

**Sources**:

- [Share your real-time location with others - Android - Google Maps Help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Comment: Can one view more than one tracked car at once on Google maps?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You are not locating a car, but a person (or more precisely a Google Account that is logged in to a device) that must be in each car. No meantion of a maximum amount of 'friends and family' meationed in their text. So assume that more than one is allowed. In the maps application it is shown as a icon with the name on the map.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt When moving on a Bus, then the position will 'hop' every few minutes from one position to another. One should look for any refresh setting that may be possible.

Comment: I have considered Google Maps, but unfortunately it seems as if the tracking stops once you set directions for a given destination.

Comment: @ST20 **Location sharing** shows you where the person is pesently (when online). You do not set directions.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I understand. In this case, Google Maps fulfills both of my criteria but not at the same time. I would like location sharing and being able to set directions at the same time.

Comment: I've found Google Maps "location sharing" to be very laggy and at times _inaccurate_. It's OK for occasional spot checks, but if you need always current/accurate locations then "location sharing" doesn't really hit the mark. (But it also doesn't _chew_ the battery like some other "better" location sharing apps - so that is a plus - you can keep it active all the time without a noticeable battery drain.)

Comment: @MrWhite It is definitely not real time per meter. And directly zooming to where the person now is  was also not available.

Answer (score 2):

One service that might be of help to you is [Glympse](https://glympse.com/solutions/#consumer-location-sharing). It is specifically designed to share your location (temporarily).

When sending a Glympse, you can specify the time your location will be available for and your destination. It doesn't show any directions, but only a trail of the route taken.

The location is only shared for a period of time you specify, so you couldn't use this to continuously see someone's location.

As long as all of your friends send you their locations, you will see all of them on a map and be able to focus on one of them at a time. The application also shows their speed and heading and leaves a trail of their past movements for some time.

Comment: Glympse is great for location sharing but won't show directions. Also last time I used it, one had to share the glympse each time one wanted to share location (i.e., we can't constantly share locations). Lastly last time I used, I could only see 1 device at a time.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt good points, I included them in my answer. When you say you could only see 1 device at a time, do you mean that only one was focused or that once you had one location shared, no one else could effectively share their location with you? (I am not sure how it works with multiple devices, so I would be glad if you clarify this part.)

Answer (score -1):

I use strava for bicycling.  I think it does everything OP is asking for.

It is for biking, but I do not think the world would explode if you used it for driving.

It would probably not even upset the records that much.  The segments are sufficiently segregated so that you will probably be on different segments.  I know because I did a combination bike ride/metro ride.  On those metro segments, I hit 50+MPH but they were separate and distinct from the roughly parallel bike segments where I usually do 15MPH.

Comment: I don't think Strava syncs live

Comment: Strava will sync live - [Strava Beacon](https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/224357527-Strava-Beacon) - but it's a premium-members-only feature, and I don't think it supports watching more than one user at once. Ditto if you meant segment times again they're synced live for premium members using the app.

Comment: You will screw up segments, and get flagged for cheating; at least set e-biking instead of cycling, which should avoid this. You're assuming well-separated bike lanes.  Round here (i) most segments are in the road proper - a phone on your handlebars would track the same line as one on the front passenger seat, (ii) a lateral match from a fair distance away is possible - I have ridden some with an optional off-road bike path and a ridable road; riding either shows up as the same if they're parallel

Comment: @ChrisH you are probably right.  My standard ride was on a bike path parallel to a limited access highway parallel to a metro line.  One day, I had a bike problem on the ride and I rode the metro home.  I did not stop my strava.  The metro tracks are very close to the bike path but strava classified it separately anyway.  Everyone who rode the "metro" segments was "cycling" really fast like me.  The system never accused me of "cheating."

Comment: @emory Strava routinely autoflags activities that are suspiciously fast. My bike rides are uploaded as runs and roughly a half of them gets flagged.

Comment: @VladimirF I wish it were automated.  In reality some other user is hitting FLAG on your ride.  Perhaps upload them as Rides to avoid stealing some runner's KOM.